# How do I use express.static() with a directory path based on the URL?

Tags: node.js, express, url, static

I am making a service involving a system where the user gets a free subdomain, like `archiebaer.blahblahblah.demo`, and I have a function to get the site config file (`siteconf()`) that contains a key called theme. I want `archiebaer.blahblahblah.demo/theme-static/style.css` to use `express.static()` to serve a folder based on that theme key.

Eg. `app.get('/theme-static', express.static("themes/ABC/theme-static"));` where ABC is the theme name.

---

Example Scenario: `johnsmith` and `archiebaer` are both users. John's config file looks something like this: `{theme:'retro'}`, and Archie's is `{theme:'slate'}`. You can get a user's config file from the express route's request parameter using `siteconf(req)`. When I go to `/theme-static/style.css` on Archie's website, I should get the file `~/projectfolder/themes/slate/style.css`, and on John's: `~/projectfolder/themes/retro/style.css`.

---

I assume the code would look something like this:

```js
app.get('/theme-static', function (req, res) {
   res.send(express.static('themes/' + siteconf(req).theme + '/theme-static/'));
});
```

Comment: Have you tried that? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: No.  You don't ever put `express.static()` inside another route.  `express.static()` returns a middleware function which is to be registered as its own middleware.  What you are trying to do is NOT what it's for, not what it works for. If you have constructed the filename, then just use `res.sendFile(filename)`.

Comment: Perhaps all  you want is `res.sendFile('themes/' + siteconf(req).theme + '/theme-static/');`

Answer (score 0):

Here was my solution:

```js
app.get('/theme-static/*', function (req, res, next) {
  var relurl = req.url.replace("/theme-static/", "");
  if (relurl === '') {
    //This is so '/theme-static/' without any file after is treated as normal 404.
    next();
    return;
  }
  var filePath = "themes/" + siteconf(req).theme + "/theme-static/" + relurl;
  if (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, filePath));
  } else {
    res.status(404).send("Invalid File");
  }
});
```

Comment: This looks like it might have some vulnerability issues to exposing files outside what you want to expose with URLs that have `../../` kind of stuff in them.  Not entirely sure, but using `relurl` without any sanitizing is what looks risky.

Comment: Also, you should NEVER use `fs.existsSync()` in a request handler.  That RUINS server scalability.  Can probably just use `res.sendFile()` directly without preflighting and then handle the error from that to send a 404.

Comment: I tested home.keytap.xyz/theme-static/..%2f..%2fREADME.md, and it was received as themes/slate/theme-static/..%2f..%2fREADME.md

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use something like:

```
app.use("/theme-static", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "pathToFolder")));
```

If the file doesn't exist, express will handle the error for you.

Comment: I know about that, but I was wondering how to use express.static when the pathToFolder can change depending on the request. My workaround seems fine though.